# Node.js (Openshift) express response not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openshift

I am using OpenShift and Node.js
I am trying to get the average - rating for each result but I cant 
get the response to work even though the console reports correctly.
I get 3.9454323 into the console , but when I git localhost:3002/getM/1 the response is blank.

```
app.get('/getM/:movieId', function(request,response) {
  var movieId = request.params.movieId;
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    user: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME || 'root',
    password: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD || '',
    port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT || '3306',
    database: 'test'
  });
  connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      response.send("error connecting to database");
      return;
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
  });
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `ratings` WHERE `movieId` = ?',[movieId], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      response.send(err);
    }
    var sum = 0;
    result.forEach(function(movie) {
      sum += movie["rating"];
      console.log(sum);
    });
    console.log(sum/result.length);
    response.send(sum/result.length);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting the `connected as id (..)` message, i.e., are you properly connected to the db?

Comment: yes I do, I even get the result sum/result.length. If i change the response to a string "test" , i get the response. is this a content type issue ?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing; what is the exact problem? the console.log is correct but the response is blank? Have you tried sending just a string as a response and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a numeric argument to `response.send()`. Here's what the express documentation says:

> res.send([body])
>
> Sends the HTTP response.
>
> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an
>   Array.

see: http://expressjs.com/api.html

Try this:

```
response.send( "" + sum/result.length );
```

**EDIT:**
BTW, if you're using an older version of express, then express may be trying to interpret the number as an HTTP status code. I'm not sure what express will do with floating point values, but in any case that's clearly not what you intended.

> Finally when a Number is given without any of the previously mentioned
>   bodies, then a response body string is assigned for you. For example
>   200 will respond will the text “OK”, and 404 “Not Found” and so on.

see: http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.send